# Transpose a table in SQL without using pivot function (netezza)

Tags: sql, database, netezza

**Table A**

```
+-------+----------+
| user  | product  |
+-------+----------+
| user1 | product1 |
| user1 | product2 |
| user1 | product6 |
+-------+----------+
```

**Table B**

```
+----------+
| product |
+----------+
| product1 |
| product2 |
| product3 |
| product4 |
| product5 |
| product6 |
+----------+
```

**Output**

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| user  | product1 | product2 | product3 | product4 | product5 | product6 |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| user1 |        1 |        1 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        1 |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

`Table B` contains all distinct products from `Table A`. It's much bigger than the example and is dynamic for each run, hence unlikely to use simple `case when` statement.

Comment: For a dynamic pivot, you need dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks! @GordonLinoff